# UserNameRequiredErrorMessage is not showing using validation summary in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

`UserNameRequiredErrorMessage` not wokring with validation summary. i have put login control. During validation process of login control, message is not coming. it is showing only asterisk symbol. I am using following code in the page which has included masterpage..

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" 
  runat="server" 
  BackColor="#F7F7DE" 
  BorderColor="#CCCC99"
  ValidatorTextStyle-ForeColor="Red" 
  PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="You must enter a password."
  UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="You must enter a user name." 
  TextBoxStyle-Width="150"
  BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
  Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt"
  TitleText="Members Login" 
  InstructionText="Please enter your user name and password for login."
  onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" 
  onloginerror="Login1_LoginError">

  <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#476042" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</asp:Login>

<asp:ValidationSummary id="ValidationSummary1" 
  ShowMessageBox="true" 
  ShowSummary="true" 
  runat="server" 
  ValidationGroup="Login1">
</asp:ValidationSummary>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not added The `ErrorMessage` attribute to your login control
See the below code I have added the Error Message attribute in the Login control

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" 
   runat="server" 
   BackColor="#F7F7DE" 
   ErrorMessage="Write your Error Message here"
   BorderColor="#CCCC99"
   ValidatorTextStyle-ForeColor="Red" 
   PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="You must enter a password."
   UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="You must enter a user name." 
   TextBoxStyle-Width="150"
   BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
   Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt"
   TitleText="Members Login" 
   InstructionText="Please enter your user name and password for login."
   onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" 
   onloginerror="Login1_LoginError">

   <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#476042" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</asp:Login>
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) about ValidationSummary:

> The summary can be displayed as a list, a bulleted list, or a single paragraph, based on the value of the DisplayMode property. The **error message** displayed in the ValidationSummary control for each validation control on the page is specified by the ErrorMessage property of each validation control. **If the ErrorMessage property of the validation control is not set, no error message is displayed** in the ValidationSummary control for that validation control.

Answer (score 0):

When you use validator with summary, you must execute thtese steps

Set `ErrorMessage="your message"` on validator (UserNameRequiredErrorMessage)

Set `Display="None"` on validator (UserNameRequiredErrorMessage)

Set `ShowSummary="true"` on summary (ValidationSummary1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using master pages & your login control is in content page, try using this workaround:

Place this code on the Page_Load Event of content page:

```
if (Login1 != null)
{
  // Replace the returned underscores with dollar signs.
  ValidationSummary1.ValidationGroup = Login1.ClientID.Replace("_", "$");
}
```